# zeppelin java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: apache-spark, garbage-collection, apache-zeppelin

I'm getting an error in zeppelin **org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.** with description **Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**.

Spark monitoring showed that GC took almost all time of task:
[image]

I started investigation and found out that the problem isn't inefficient task in zeppelin, but the problem is how we run spark. Zeppelin provides the **built-in spark** and the way to use **external spark**(you can set SPARK_HOME in conf/zeppelin-env.sh or in zeppelin gui). When I'm using built-in spark everything work good but for external spark I'm getting **GC overhead limit exceeded** exception for the same task.

What is the difference between this two ways of running spark and how I can fix GC overhead limit exceeded exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference was in available memory for driver. I found out it by zeppelin-interpreter-spark.log: `memorystore started with capacity ...`. When I used bult-in spark it was `2004.6 MB` for external spark it was `366.3 MB`.

So, I increased available memory for driver by setting `spark.driver.memory` in zeppelin gui. It solved the problem.